# Blat hebrew encoding

Tags: windows, encoding, cmd, hebrew, blat

I have problem with hebrew encoding in blat. I use this command in specific windows program:

```
blat $mailfile -charset "UTF-8" -subject "$subjectALL" -f $sender -to $receiver -cc $blind -attach "$6" > $blatoutput
```

My problem is when email come it have wrong subject charecters. I try fix it by changing -charset in command to windows-1255/ISO8859/OEM 862 but nothing help.

I want to see correct hebrew characters in mail subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RFC does not allow 8bit characters in the envelope. You should convert the subject text to base64 encoded string:

```
export x=`base64 <<EOF
$subjectALL
EOF`
blat $mailfile -charset "UTF-8" -subject "=?UTF-8?B?$x" -f $sender -to $receiver -cc $blind -attach "$6" > $blatoutput
```